# Cannot run c file in clion

Tags: c, cmake, clion

I configure CLion toolchain with MinGW and set environment variable in Windows 7, and I also can use GCC to complile and built and run `hello.c` in `cmd` console.

```
F:\c_cpp\
|-- cmake-build-debug\
|-- CMakeLists.txt
|-- hello.c
|-- library.c
`-- library.h
```

The following is my CMake file:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.8)
project(c_cpp)

set(CMAKE_C_STANDARD 99)

set(SOURCE_FILES library.c library.h hello.c)
add_library(c_cpp ${SOURCE_FILES})
```

When I click run button and choose "run c_cpp", the error happened.

> Error running 'c_cpp': Cannot run program "F:\c_cpp\library.c" (in directory "F:\c_cpp"): CreateProcess error=193, %1 不是有效的 Win32 应用程序。

What should I do?

Comment: Please, don'ẗ add screenshots, rather add the content of the actual files instead. And the text of the error message. This makes it easier to read.

Comment: Consider also compiling on the command line, or writing manually your own `Makefile`

Comment: The underlying reason of this error is :i choose (c library) when i open a new project,i should choose (c executable),and everything will be fine

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are building a library, which you can't execute.

If `hello.c` is an application using your library, change

```
add_library(c_cpp ${SOURCE_FILES})
```

to

```
add_executable(hello ${SOURCE_FILES})
```

After which you should be able to run `hello`.

Comment: I am afraid the issue here is that the c file is directly being executed and not compiled. See "Cannot run program F:/c_cpp/library.c". The error code 193 also confirms the same. See [error codes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681382(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: Yes, he's also tryhing to execute `library.c`, hence I asked him to execute `hello` after doing the other changes...

Comment: Actually he is trying to run `c_cpp` which is analogous to your `hello`. I think the issue is not with the CMakeLists.txt but with the build system target

Comment: I  take your advice and delete 'library.c','library.h',get the result i want. I just want to simply execute my c file,the build system really confuse me.I haven't touch c for many years.

Comment: Well, when building an executable, you need to use `add_executable()`, not `add_library()`, which in turn is used to build either a static and dynamic library.

Comment: You cannot *simply execute a C file*, you practically need to compile it (into some executable).